# Unset color set in Theme Customizer

Tags: theme-customizer, color-picker

I'm building a theme using the Theme Customizer and have a few options with color pickers. It seems as though once you set a color using the color picker, there's no way to clear/remove/ unset it, is that right?

If you haven't saved your settings yet, you can hit the cancel button (though you'd lose all your other unsaved settings) -- but once it's saved, it's set in stone? Or am I missing something?